# Как узнать атрибут input max в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Как получить значение `input max` в JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так

```js
 var maxElement = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("max");
console.log("Max ="+ maxElement);
```

```html
<form name="a">
  <input name="b" type="number" max="10"/>
</form>
```

Comment: простой вопрос, простой, добротный ответ (+)

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(document.forms.a.b.max)
```

```html
<form name="a">
  <input name="b" type="number" max="10"/>
</form>
```